# Problems when running Maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm working on a project on github and using Eclipse Luna.
Before, I could modify my Java code and then compiled it without "mvn clean package" and then the program ran properly. But today after deleting and cloning the project, each time I modify my code, I have to run command "mvn clean package". Otherwise, it just run the old code and doesnt update the new code. This's really incovenient and waste of time because it will download all the dependencies from the beginning and rebuild the project.

Does any one know how to fix this please ? Thank you :)

Comment: Do you use Maven for `Java web application project` or `Java desktop application`? If you use Maven for `Java web application project`, you should remember that, after  clean, build project, you must **deploy application** to Java application server to **see changing**.

Comment: Is "Build Automatically" enabled in project menu?

Comment: did you configure the project as a maven project in eclipse (right click on project --> configure --> convert to maven project)?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :**

1. Right click the src/main/java folder in the Package Explorer // where you added new files
2. Select Build Path -> Configure Output Folder
3. Enter target/classes, click OK